# Which demonstrative pronoun should be used in the following example?

Tags: pronouns, demonstratives, social-media

I've made a [story](https://www.instagram.com/stories/lidght/3008465392905986578/) on Instagram, on which I've put a link to an image with music.

[image: T-shirt]

There you see a T-shirt with the titles of songs from the Untitled blink-182 album. On my story I wrote: "I love every song of **that** album".

My question is: is "**that**" the right pronoun to use, considering that the story has a link to another post, which points to an album? Or can we say that this T-shirt is, speaking in terms of grammar rules, close enough to use "**this**"? Maybe there's some other rule I'm not aware of, by which I should've used "this" or is the use of "that" in this case is fine?

Comment: Unless there are multiple items that you need to distinguish, there's little difference between "this" and "that". Either will be acceptable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of speech in question is not a pronoun but a determiner; this is so because you find it right before a noun.

- This is a new machine. (*pronoun*)
- This machine is new. (*determiner*)

In the context you describe, if the music playing along the display of the image is that of the album, it seems that "this" is better if it must appear before the music is played; if it appears after the image had a chance to be seen and the music listened to, then "that" seems more appropriate. This can be inferred from a principle stated in *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swann.

> **565** **This** and **that** demonstrative pronouns and  determiners)
>
> […]
> **3 time**
> *This/these* can refer to situations and experiences which are going on or just about to start.
>
> - *I like **this** music. What is it?*
> - *Listen to **this**. You'll like it.* (NOT <s>*Listen to **that***</s>…)
> - *Watch **this**. **This** is a police message.*
>
> *That/those* can refer to experiences which have just finished, or which are more distant in the past.
>
> - ***That** was nice. What was it?* (NOT <s>***This** was nice*</s>…)
> - *Did you see **that***? *Who said **that***?
> - *Have you ever heard from **that** Scottish boy you used to go out with?*  (NOT … <s>***this** Scottish boy you used to go out with*</s>…)
>
> *That* can show that something has come to an end.
>
> - … *and **that**'s how it happened*.
> - *'Anything else?' 'No, **that**'s all, thanks.' 'Right, **that**'ll be £7.50 altogether.'* (in a shop)
> - *OK. **That**'s it. I'm leaving. It was nice knowing you.*
> - *Well, **that**'s **that**. Another day's work finished. Let's go home.*
>
> Note that *this morning* can refer to a finished period (if one is speaking later the same day); *this afternoon* and *this spring/summer/autumn* are used in the same way.

Comment: I didn't get the impression that there's anything playing. It's just a pictue of a shirt with song titles, and the determiner is referring to the album that contains those songs.

Comment: "that" may be better because it's conceptually at a distance, since we're indirecting through the shirt and song titles.

Comment: @Barmar I went by the words "image with music" although I considered the possibility of the music turning  on as the image appears not obvious at all;  it seems fairly sure that one way or another the music is from the album. It depends on where it is mentioned that he/she loves the album though (it is written in the story). So, along the supposition that the visitor  goes about his inquiry sequentially, if the words are before the link, they are about something about to happen, and "this" would be better, if after, then "that" is better since we can suppose the experience came to an end.

Comment: I didn't notice that phrase before, I think you're right.

Comment: I'm a little confused about this sequence that you described. My way of thinking about this was just as @Barmar's. Well, I suppose that the reader probably won't be able to recognize the album just by a T-shirt and hence will go onto the linked post. He doesn't have to, though.
I guess, the right option was to use "this"

Comment: @whatserface I understand that the demonstrative is to be used in the story; if you tell your reader that you love a particular album before they reach the link and have a chance to listen to it, then the listening is an experience just about to start, and so "this" seems better according to some accepted usage. If on the contrary your assertion followss the link, then your reader is expected to have had some experience involving the music (maybe he/she listened to all of it); in this case it is an experience that just finished, so "that" is more appropriate. (1/3)

Comment: @whatserface Here is a parallel you should identify without problems. suppose you are with some friend and that you want to know what he/she thinks about some songs you like; before putting on a record you are more likely to say "Let's listen to this." (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%27s+listen+to+this%2Clet%27s+listen+to+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3that); (2/3)

Comment: @whatserface  however, after you listened to something together, you are more likely to say "How did you like that?" (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=how+did+you+like+this%2Chow+did+you+like+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3). (3/3)